# Java moving a image up and down, animated motion

Tags: java, image, paint, repaint

I'm wondering how I can move an image after it has been drawn?

Heres my code for drawing the image:

```
public int probeX = 500;
public int Minerals = 400;
public int drawProbeA, drawProbe = 0;

public void init() {
   // Images Call
   probe = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "image/probe.png");
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
   if (drawProbe == 1) {
      for (int k = 0; k < drawProbeA; k++) {

         g.drawImage(probe, probeX, 474, 50, 50, this);
         probeX += 50;
      }
      probeX = 500;
   }
}

public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) {
   // Clicking on the probe icon
   if (x > 1068 && x < 1119 && y > 785 && y < 832 && onNexus == 1
         && Minerals >= 50) {
      drawProbeA += 1;
      drawProbe = 1;
      Minerals -= 50;
   }

   return true;
}
```

How can I make it so that after the images are drawn, that hitting an icon will cause the image to be auto moved down the y-axis (like 50 pixels)? Basically, like sliding the image down with an animation? And then stop and then move back up to the orginal spot.

I am using an Applet and would like the animation to loop repeatedly. Thanks.

Comment: How many additional pylons have you constructed so far?

Comment: *"I am using an Applet"* In the 2nd decade of the 3rd millennium, it is time to stop using AWT (`Applet`) and instead use Swing (`JApplet`).  But then the question becomes, why an applet rather than a frame launched from a link using JWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a global variable, or another variable somewhere, that indicates that...

1. The image needs to move
2. How far in the Y direction it has moved already
3. Which direction it is going (up or down)

When you have this, you need to add code to your `paint()` method to draw the image in the correct spot.

You would also need a `Timer` or `Thread` that will tell the component to `repaint()` every few milliseconds, and change your global variables so that it will repaint it lower/higher.

So, as a bit of an example, you might have some global variables like this...

```
int yPosition = 0;
boolean goingDown = true;
```

When you need to start your animation, start a `Timer` that calls the following over and over...

```
if (goingDown == true){
    // if we've gone down 50 pixels, start going up again
    if (yPosition <= 0){
        goingDown = false;
        yPosition++;
    }
    else {
        yPosition--; // move it down 1 pixel
    }
}
else {
    // if we're going up and we reach 0, go down again
    if (yPosition >= 50){
        goingDown = true;
        yPosition--;
    }
    else {
        yPosition++; // move it up1 pixel
    }
}

component.repaint(); // this will call the paint() method
```

Not your paint method just need to draw your image at the different position. Just change the `g.drawImage(probe,probeX,474,50,50,this);` like to include the yPosition...

```
g.drawImage(probe,probeX,474+yPosition,50,50,this);
```

This should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you give me a example on how to do this with code please?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try first, using the suggestions I have given. We are more likely to help you better if you try first, then come back to us with any errors/problems you are having. Have a look at the Timer and Thread classes to see whether you can figure them out - they're required to make your code repaint for the animation effect.

Comment: i tried  private void startProbe()
 {
  for(int k = 425; k > 525; k+=10)
  {
   probeY+= 10;
   delay(100);
   if(k > probeY)
   {
    System.out.print("Done");
   }
  }
 }

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but I'm not sure if delay() is the best thing to use - I'd at least investigate a Timer or Thread so that you don't lock up the GUI thread. You also need to call repaint() in your timer so that it can re-draw the image. See my edited answer for some guidelines.

Comment: Hi, once it gets to the bottom it kids just bounces up and down and doesn't go back to its original spot

Comment: If you're using code similar to my big `if-else` statement, I might have had the `yPosition <= 0` and `yPosition >= 50` code the wrong way around. Refer to my corrected code.